# bbswitch & bumblebee, card starting one every two call

Tags: xorg, nvidia, bumblebee

I'm trying to set up bumblebee for using my Nvidia card (GT 750M) for running opengl 4 applications.

I installed  intel-dri, xf86-video-intel, nvidia, bumblebee and bbswitch.

I set up /etc/modprobe.d/bbswitch.conf

```
options bbswitch load_state=0 unload_state=1
```

Yet I have a stange issue, at first call my program doesn't start :

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch
0000:02:00.0 OFF
$ optirun glxgears
[ 1500.270330] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
[ 1500.270357] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
$ cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch
0000:02:00.0 ON
$ optirun glxgears
>> WORKS !!!
$ cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch
0000:02:00.0 OFF
```

when looking at /var/log/Xorg.8.log I have

```
[  1491.638] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1491.639] (EE) Failed to load module "kbd" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1500.268] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:2:0:0.  Please
[  1500.268] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     check your system's kernel log for additional error
[  1500.268] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     messages and refer to Chapter 8: Common Problems in the
[  1500.268] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     README for additional information.
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. It seams that it comes to option in kernel loading.

I just added

```
rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1
```

to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line in /etc/default/grub before regererating my grub.cfg file

link : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169742